# Specific css positioning / dynamic width with auto margin

Tags: css, height, positioning, margin

Made an image for better understanding of the problem.

[image: picture showing the problem]

Need code for .bgimage and .content div

Is this even possible for crossbrowser css (IE7+ and other major browsers) without any scripting?

Comment: Where is your problem ?

Comment: I simply dont know how to do this in css.

Comment: I uploaded your picture, now waiting for the revision. Meanwhile, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This is indeed very doable, but don't expect anyone just to do all the work for you. [Here looks like a great CSS tutorial](http://www.csstutorial.net/part-2/layout-page-part1.php), and Google will throw you some more, you are looking for `CSS layout design` or similars. Also, read StackOverflow's [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking questions, please.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to  use `float` on .bgimage and .content

Comment: but jamauss, how? If I float them left both, the right side of the .content div wont be aligned to the right side of the header and footer( because .bgimage div havent got its width specified, it has to be 100% of the gap). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Making this picture is a great start, you know have a clear view of what you need. As Frank Presencia Fandos said try the "self study" way. For that kind of structure you just need html and css. There are loads of websites with tutorials to help you. Come back if you face some problems :)

Comment: I really tried hard to think about this one, but maybe I have some fundamental flaw in understanding some of the css principles, because I cant see the way how should I position those things to have it work like on picture. I feel embarassed, because I really try to do things myself before asking others. Will look on it one more time and try to find some tutorials.

Comment: Are the positions and sizes of the divs hardcoded? Or they are variable somehow?

Comment: Width of the .header, .content. and .footer are hardcoded, but as said on the picture, width of the .bgimage needs to be 100% of the gap between left edge of the browser screen and left edge of the .content div. Also the right edge of the .content div need to be in line with right edge of the .header and .footer

Comment: I am certainly missing something, because width of the .bgimage div will vary across different monitor resolutions and I cant find a way in css to specify it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was actually a bit longer than expected, but I got your picture in real life. Don't ask again any questions here without doing more research first and writing some actual code.

**[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hUT3s/4/embedded/result/)**

### The code

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id = "header">
  </div>
  <div id = "bgimage">
  </div>
  <div id = "content">
  </div>
  <span class = "clear"></span>
  <div id = "footer">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*
  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

body
  {
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }

#header
  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  }

#bgimage
  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
  }

#content
  {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: blue;
  }

.clear
  {
  clear: both;
  }

#footer
  {
  position: relative;
  top: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

Note: I haven't optimized the CSS, there's some work that could be done there.

[The code is also here](http://jsfiddle.net/hUT3s/4/)

### Explanation

Elements that I've used in the code (you might want to google them):

- CSS Reset
- CSS clear
- absolute positioning CSS
- relative positioning CSS

Comment: I really feel sad because I gave you an impression of someone, who cant spend few minutes googling for the result. I am not like that. And your solution is not working, the divs are just overlapping each other. It was clearly specified that the width of .bgimage has to be width of the gap between content and edge of the screen. In your example, the width is 50%;

Comment: I didn't intend to offend you either, I'm sorry. The `shown` bgimage goes in the space of what you specified... but the div is actually below. I'll fix it if you really need it that way.

Comment: You will probably ask why I have a problem with your solution. It is because I wanted the .bgimage div to have a big background image(hence the name of the div:) aligned right which would not cause the scrollbar. In your solution, the image is partly overlapped with content bar.

Comment: It's weird that you have a background image just here and that stretches horizontally but not vertically though. What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: I updated my answer. But beware [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/calc) and Opera.

Comment: I would be glad for IE6+, Mozilla, Chrome, Opera and Safari, if it is possible. The image is portrait, which is mostly visible on 960px(1024x768) and completely visible on higher resolutions. I simply run out of space when designing, but havent wanted to limit the design of my pages by compatibilityfor low resolution monitors.

Comment: Check the link I put on support for calc(). The div is not overlapping now, it might be a problem with the background (the background is wider than the div and gets cut off).

Comment: Havent noticed you changed only the demo, going to try it

Comment: [It's working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/hUT3s/5/embedded/result/), with this [random image](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-WLgMgyrl-p0/TyqmaQzwRvI/AAAAAAAAQdA/YUNHPSicp3U/s1600/oldpaperscrolls5+BackgroundFairy.jpg). Did you put `  background-size: 100% 100%;`?

Comment: Yes, it is working. I was just googling and trying how calc() behave in older browsers. I will mark this as acceptable since you put your time to that, although I am not sure whether I use it( will depend on whether I find any acceptable mid-way compatibility for older browser). Not saying that to be just smart-ass, but I am living in eastern Europe and there is still high percentage of people using old IE(6 and mostly 7). Thats why I also originally asked, if it is cross-browser possible.

Comment: Also the body width: 960px might be a obstacle for future design changes, even thought I can handle it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. You can add another value for right before, like this: `right: 55%; right: calc(50% + 220px);`, so if it fails in some older browsers it doesn't fail so much.